# suddenly, getUser became to return 0.(PHP 3.1.1 SDK)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

Only 10 hours ago, if I call `$facebook->getUser()`, I can get the correct `user_id`, but now, it always returns 0. Of cource, I have not changed my code.

There is another strange point.

`redirect_url` contains:

> ?sate=9b1772342342...&code=9b177asd2l..&base_domain=9b1772.3423#*=*

I can't release the site.. Please help!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think this is a Facebook bug, I just finished figuring it out myself. You need to alter the Base_Facebook class, and add in a new query param to strip out. The base_domain param is being accidentally appended to the redirect url, hopefully a fix will be rolled out soon.

```
  /**
   * List of query parameters that get automatically dropped when rebuilding
   * the current URL.
   */
  protected static $DROP_QUERY_PARAMS = array(
    'code',
    'state',
    'signed_request',
    'base_domain', // this is the one you need to add
  );
```

Comment: This is now acknowledged by FB as a bug: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/220904677985962