# php sdk working only in https connections

Tags: ssl, facebook-php-sdk

First of all, please do not downvote this post. This is my observance that the php sdk only works in https connections. All the websites which I know(including mine) which have an http connection cannot connect with facebook at all and the $user returns 0 because of which many users are suffering. Please look at a question posted for bounty in stackoverflow -> [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17291721/facebook-getuser-suddenly-stopped-working/17386890#17386890). I initially thought that the reason for the problem was blocked ports but now, even in my website $user returns 0.

I want to know that is here anyone who has the php sdk working in a http connection? or else I will buy an SSL soon.

Comment: Did you check out my link and if so can you upvote my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @CharlesBlackwell the php sdk does not work in your link even. You must recheck it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! I changed my server and the php sdk works perfect in http connection. However, the link which @Charles gave did not work

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I do have it working with just http. You can check out my site:
http://www.pittsburghpartycentral.com/connect.php

Comment: I just checked it. I was able to login to FB, see my info and log out.

Comment: @BenLind I had someone else login with their account and it works fine.